# Understanding CSS class selector use in meteor

Tags: css, meteor

I am using `meteor` to try to style a clicked item in a list but am having some trouble understanding the proper way to define the `CSS` selector.

I have an unordered list in `html`:

```
<template name="template1">
  <ul>
  {{#each document}}
    <li class='document {{selectedClass}}'>{{name}}: {{num}}</li>
  {{/each}}
  </ul>
```

so that when the following client-side `JavaScript` runs, the clicked item should receive a class of `'document selected'` while the others should have a class of `'document'`

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Template.template1.selectedClass = function (){
    var documentId = this._id;
    var selectedDocument = Session.get('selectedDocument');
    if (selectedDocument === documentId) {
      return 'selected';
    };
  };

  Template.leaderboard.events ({
    'click li.document': function() {
      var documentId = this._id;
      Session.set('selectedDocument', documentId);
    }
  )}

};
```

and as a `CSS` selector I am using

```
.selected {
  background-color:grey;
}
```

which seems to work, but I don't understand why. The class is called `'document selected'` but `.selected` seems to pick it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiple classes in html.

For eg:

```
<div class="foo bar baz">Foo bar and baz</div>
```

Now, you can use any of them:

```
.foo{
  color: red;
}
```

Or, all of them without space:

```
.foo.bar.baz{
   color: green;
}
```

---

> But, why we use it ?

If you have multiple divs with the same class as the following:

```
<div class="foo bar baz">Foo bar and baz</div>
<div class="bar">Foo bar and baz</div>
```

You may override the css rules as below:

```
.bar{
  color: red;
}
/*.bar element but which has foo class also*/
.foo.bar{
  color: blue;/*this overrides the color in class="foo bar" previously defined red color*/
}
```

You may learn more about it here:

http://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a class named `document selected` as this is automatically TWO classes in CSS. Spaces in class names or ids is not allowed since space is used a a separator for multiple classes/ids.

So for an element like `<div class="document selected">` css from the following css selectors applies:

`.document { ... }`

`.selected { ... }`

`.document.selected { ... }`

The first two selectors apply to every element that has the named class in its class attribute. The 3rd applies only to elements that have BOTH class names.